# Recursion translation with error on the second loop

Tags: postgresql, function, recursion

The [original with-recursion code](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/441995/7505) is

```sql
    CREATE FUNCTION test.ST_GeoHashAdjacent(text,text,OUT neighbor TEXT) 
     ...
     BEGIN
      If STRPOS(_g_bd[__ai], _h_lc) > 0 AND _h_pf <> '' THEN
        _h_pf := ST_GeoHashAdjacent(_h_pf, $2); -- recursion!
      END IF;
      neighbor := _h_pf || _b_32[STRPOS(_g_nb[__ai], _h_lc)];
     END;
```

I translated from original to a WHILE loop instead recursion, supposing **better performance**.

I only do a expansion and substitution ... And some error, see testing results:

```sql
    BEGIN
      WHILE STRPOS(_g_bd[__ai], _h_lc) > 0 AND _h_pf <> '' THEN
         pf2:= _h_pf;
         _h_pf := ... -- same as test.ST_GeoHashAdjacent(pf2, $2) 
      END IF;
      neighbor := _h_pf || _b_32[STRPOS(_g_nb[__ai], _h_lc)];
    END;
```

---

### Details

This `test.function` library is the complete "translation code":

```sql
DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS test CASCADE; 
CREATE SCHEMA test; 

CREATE FUNCTION test.ST_GeoHashAdjacent(
  IN  ref_hash  TEXT,
  IN  direction TEXT,
  OUT neighbor  TEXT
) LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' IMMUTABLE STRICT AS
  $FUNCTION$
    DECLARE
      _lu_d TEXT   := 'n s e w';
      _b_32 TEXT[] := ARRAY[
        '0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','j','k','m','n','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'
      ];
      _g_nb TEXT[] := ARRAY[
        'p0r21436x8zb9dcf5h7kjnmqesgutwvy', 'bc01fg45238967deuvhjyznpkmstqrwx',
        '14365h7k9dcfesgujnmqp0r2twvyx8zb', '238967debc01fg45kmstqrwxuvhjyznp',
        'bc01fg45238967deuvhjyznpkmstqrwx', 'p0r21436x8zb9dcf5h7kjnmqesgutwvy',
        '238967debc01fg45kmstqrwxuvhjyznp', '14365h7k9dcfesgujnmqp0r2twvyx8zb'
      ];
      _g_bd TEXT[] := ARRAY[
        'prxz',     'bcfguvyz',
        '028b',     '0145hjnp',
        'bcfguvyz', 'prxz',
        '0145hjnp', '028b'
      ];
                      
      _h_pf TEXT   := LEFT($1, -1);
      _h_lc TEXT   := RIGHT($1, 1);
    
      _h_tp INT    := LENGTH($1) % 2;
      
      __ai  INT    := STRPOS(_lu_d, $2) + _h_tp;
          pf2 TEXT;
    BEGIN
      WHILE STRPOS(_g_bd[__ai], _h_lc) > 0 AND _h_pf <> '' LOOP
        -- _h_pf := ST_GeoHashAdjacent(_h_pf, $2) =
        pf2:= _h_pf;
        _h_pf := LEFT(pf2, -1);
        _h_lc := RIGHT(pf2, 1);
        _h_tp := LENGTH(pf2) % 2;
        __ai  := STRPOS(_lu_d, $2) + _h_tp;
        _h_pf := _h_pf || _b_32[STRPOS(_g_nb[__ai], _h_lc)];
      END LOOP;
          
      neighbor := _h_pf || _b_32[STRPOS(_g_nb[__ai], _h_lc)];
    END;
  $FUNCTION$
;

CREATE FUNCTION test.ST_GeoHashNeighbors(
  IN  center_hash TEXT,
  OUT neighbors   TEXT[]
) LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' IMMUTABLE STRICT AS
  $FUNCTION$
    BEGIN
      neighbors := ARRAY[
        test.ST_GeoHashAdjacent(test.ST_GeoHashAdjacent($1, 'n'), 'w'),
        test.ST_GeoHashAdjacent($1, 'n'),
        test.ST_GeoHashAdjacent(test.ST_GeoHashAdjacent($1, 'n'), 'e'),
        test.ST_GeoHashAdjacent($1, 'e'),
        test.ST_GeoHashAdjacent(test.ST_GeoHashAdjacent($1, 's'), 'e'),
        test.ST_GeoHashAdjacent($1, 's'),
        test.ST_GeoHashAdjacent(test.ST_GeoHashAdjacent($1, 's'), 'w'),
        test.ST_GeoHashAdjacent($1, 'w')
      ];
    END;
  $FUNCTION$
```

##### Testing

```sql
SELECT ST_GeoHashNeighbors(ghs)   original  FROM (SELECT unnest('{6,6g,06}'::text[])) t(ghs);

SELECT test.ST_GeoHashNeighbors(ghs)   test  FROM (SELECT unnest('{6,6g,06}'::text[])) t(ghs);
```

Result:

```
         original          
---------------------------
 {9,d,e,7,5,4,1,3}
 {6s,6u,7h,75,74,6f,6d,6e}
 {05,07,0e,0d,09,03,01,04}

           test            
---------------------------
 {9,d,e,7,5,4,1,3}
 {6s,6u,77,77,77,6f,6d,6e}
 {05,07,0e,0d,09,03,01,04}
```

Diff line:  `{6s,6u,77,77,77,6f,6d,6e}`

---

### Commented solution

Thanks @geozelot, using your clues (values `ai0` and `lc0`  not  changed for the final assignment) we solved the simplest test:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION test.ST_GeoHashAdjacent(
  IN  ref_hash  TEXT,
  IN  direction TEXT,
  OUT neighbor  TEXT
) LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' IMMUTABLE STRICT AS
  $FUNCTION$
    DECLARE
      _lu_d TEXT   := 'n s e w';
      _b_32 TEXT[] := ARRAY[
        '0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','j','k','m','n','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'
      ];
      _g_nb TEXT[] := ARRAY[
        'p0r21436x8zb9dcf5h7kjnmqesgutwvy', 'bc01fg45238967deuvhjyznpkmstqrwx',
        '14365h7k9dcfesgujnmqp0r2twvyx8zb', '238967debc01fg45kmstqrwxuvhjyznp',
        'bc01fg45238967deuvhjyznpkmstqrwx', 'p0r21436x8zb9dcf5h7kjnmqesgutwvy',
        '238967debc01fg45kmstqrwxuvhjyznp', '14365h7k9dcfesgujnmqp0r2twvyx8zb'
      ];
      _g_bd TEXT[] := ARRAY[
        'prxz',     'bcfguvyz',
        '028b',     '0145hjnp',
        'bcfguvyz', 'prxz',
        '0145hjnp', '028b'
      ];
                      
      _h_pf TEXT   := LEFT($1, -1);
      _h_lc TEXT   := RIGHT($1, 1);
    
      _h_tp INT    := LENGTH($1) % 2;
      
      __ai  INT    := STRPOS(_lu_d, $2) + _h_tp;
      ai0  int;
      lc0 TEXT;
          pf2 TEXT;
    BEGIN
          ai0 := __ai;
          lc0 := _h_lc;
      WHILE STRPOS(_g_bd[__ai], _h_lc) > 0 AND _h_pf <> '' LOOP
        -- _h_pf := ST_GeoHashAdjacent(_h_pf, $2) =
        pf2:= _h_pf;
        _h_pf := LEFT(pf2, -1);
        _h_lc := RIGHT(pf2, 1);
        _h_tp := LENGTH(pf2) % 2;
        __ai  := STRPOS(_lu_d, $2) + _h_tp;
        _h_pf := _h_pf || _b_32[STRPOS(_g_nb[__ai], _h_lc)];
      END LOOP;
          
      neighbor := _h_pf || _b_32[STRPOS(_g_nb[ai0], lc0)];
    END;
  $FUNCTION$
;
```

The result line `{6s,6u,7h,75,74,6f,6d,6e}` now is the same, no difference... **But** expanding tests, we get again many fails:

```sql
SELECT row_number() OVER () as id,
       *, original=test AS diff
FROM (
  SELECT ST_GeoHashNeighbors(ghs) original,
       test.ST_GeoHashNeighbors(ghs) test
  FROM (SELECT unnest('{6g,6gf,6gf21,s012}'::text[])) t0(ghs)
) t1;
```

| ID | original | test | diff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | {6s,6u,7h,75,74,6f,6d,6e} | {6s,6u,7h,75,74,6f,6d,6e} | t |
| 2 | {6u1,6u4,6u5,6gg,6ge,6gd,6g9,6gc} | {6u1,6u4,6u5,6gg,6ge,6gd,6g9,6gc} | t |
| 3 | {6gf22,6gf23,6gf26,6gf24,6gdrf,6gdrc,6gdrb,6gf20} | {6gf22,6gf23,6gf26,6gf24,6gfqf,6gfqc,6gfqb,6gf20} | f |
| 4 | {s011,s013,s019,s018,kpcx,kpcr,kpcp,s010} | {s011,s013,s019,s018,s09x,s09r,s09p,s010} | f |

The test_ID 3 have original `6gdrf,6gdrc,6gdrb` and ID  4 `kpcx,kpcr,kpcp`.

#### DO WHILE loop

A good solution to simplify is something as

```sql
    BEGIN
      _h_pf := $1;
      LOOP
        _h_lc := RIGHT(_h_pf, 1);
        _h_tp := LENGTH(_h_pf) % 2;
        _h_pf := LEFT(_h_pf, -1);
        __ai  := STRPOS(_lu_d, $2) + _h_tp;
        neighbor := _h_pf || _b_32[STRPOS(_g_nb[__ai], _h_lc)];
        EXIT WHEN NOT(_h_pf <> '' AND STRPOS(_g_bd[__ai], _h_lc) > 0);
        _h_pf := neighbor;
      END LOOP;
    END;
```

Comment: You need to introduce loop variables for `__ai` and `_h_lc` - their pre-loop values must not be changed for the final assignment!

Comment: Thanks @geozelot (!), the solution is near, but not there yet: I edited the question notes, see the last one, with more tests.

Comment: The original recursion initialization is bound to the entry condition, so a DO WHILE loop is the wrong approach. In any way, the performance of looped approach in *PL/pgSQL* is not better than the recursive implementation. I doubt that a *C* language implementation would gain any significant speed boosts, either - recursion should be optimized to some degree in multi-paradigm languages, but I may be wrong. A pure stack based approach might be. You may want to try to find a way to get rid of calling the function 12 times in the outer function...

Comment: Thanks @geozelot. Yes, I agree that in some cases recursion can be faster than LOOP... And in many cases the performance gain with looping is marginal.  But I must check it by test, or  a good *benchmark*.   The C++ implementation is a big investment, and this earlier PgSQL-test  is cheaper.